# How to calculate average of subsets of columns in csv?

Tags: csv, awk

I have a very large CSV file that looks something as follows:

```
#       col1    col2    col3
1       1       7       9
2       2       8       10
3       3       9       11
4       4       10      12
5       5       11      13
6       6       12      14
```

For all columns, I would like to calculate the average of each consecutive two fields, then offset to the next two. For instance, in `col1` average of `1` and `2` is the **first** cell of the resulting column, the average of `3` and `4` is the **second** cell of the resulting column. So, the new column size is **half** the original `col1`.

The output of the script should look as follows for the provided sample file above:

```
#       col1    col2    col3
1       1.5     7.5     9.5
2       3.5     9.5     11.5
3       5.5     11.5    13.5
```

This problem seems like a good [one] to be solved with AWK, but I'm still new to using AWK.

Any pointers are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took the liberty to generalize Jonathan Leffler's answer to cover the `Nth` case for size of the average window and offset.

I wrote an `awk` script (I called it `avewithoffset`) as follows:

```
#!bin/awk
BEGIN{
    FS=OFS="\t";
    n=5; }
NR==1 { print; next;}
(NR-1)%n!=0 { for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) old[i] += $i; }
(NR-1)%n==0 { for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++)
              { $i = ($i + old[i])/n; old[i] = 0; }
              $1 = int( (NR-1)/n );
              print; }
```

**Notice** that `n=5`.

I fed the following file to it:

```
#   col1    col2    col3
1   1       16      31
2   2       17      32
3   3       18      33
4   4       19      34
5   5       20      35
6   6       21      36
7   7       22      37
8   8       23      38
9   9       24      39
10  10      25      40
11  11      26      41
12  12      27      42
13  13      28      43
14  14      29      44
15  15      30      45
```

And the resulting file looks like:

```
#   col1    col2    col3
1   3       18      33
2   8       23      38
3   13      28      43
```

Comment: The use of `NR-1` is slightly neater than in my generalized code.

Answer (score 2):

It can be done with `awk`.

```
awk 'BEGIN   { OFS = "\t" }
     NR  ==1 { print; next } # Print header
     NR%2==0 { for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) old[i] = $i; }
     NR%2==1 { for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) $i = ($i + old[i])/2
               $1 = (NR-1)/2; print }'
```

1. Set the output field separator to tab.
2. Print the header line and skip to the next line.
3. For the even lines, save the values in fields 2 to the end in the `old` array.
4. For the odd lines (after the first), calculate the average of the old and current field values.  Set the line number.  Print the result.

Sample output:

```
#       col1    col2    col3
1       1.5     7.5     9.5
2       3.5     9.5     11.5
3       5.5     11.5    13.5
```

#### Generalizing for groups of N rows

This script takes an argument which is the number of rows to group together, defaulting to 2 if no argument is specified.  As outlined in a comment, the code needs to reset the `old` array values to 0, and sum values rather than assign.

```
$ cat x.awk
awk -v N=${1:-2} \
    'BEGIN   { OFS = "\t" }
     NR  ==1 { print; next } # Print header
     NR%N!=1 { for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) old[i] += $i }
     NR%N==1 { for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) $i = ($i + old[i])/N
               $1 = int((NR-1)/N)
               print
               for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) old[i] = 0
             }' data
$ cat data
#       col1    col2    col3
1       1       7       9
2       2       8       10
3       3       9       11
4       4       10      12
5       5       11      13
6       6       12      14
7       7       14      17
8       8       16      19
9       9       18      22
10      10      20      26
11      11      22      28
12      12      24      29
$ bash x.awk 2
#       col1    col2    col3
1       1.5     7.5     9.5
2       3.5     9.5     11.5
3       5.5     11.5    13.5
4       7.5     15      18
5       9.5     19      24
6       11.5    23      28.5
$ bash x.awk 3
#       col1    col2    col3
1       2       8       10
2       5       11      13
3       8       16      19.3333
4       11      22      27.6667
$ bash x.awk 4
#       col1    col2    col3
1       2.5     8.5     10.5
2       6.5     13.25   15.75
3       10.5    21      26.25
$ bash x.awk 6
#       col1    col2    col3
1       3.5     9.5     11.5
2       9.5     19      23.5
$
```

If you want partial groups printed out at the end, add an appropriate `END` block, which will need to divide by the number of partial rows rather than the number of rows.

Comment: My question may have not been clear. I used the average of two rows as an example, what if we make it `N` number of fields to average and skip?

Comment: Your question definitely makes no mention of N>2.  Adapt my answer accordingly...you can think about how to generalize my N=2 to your N=3 case.  You'll need to reset the old array values to 0, and sum rather than assign.

Comment: There's just no point to the rest of us contributing answers when Jonathan Leffler answers first.  :-)  +1 btw.

Comment: My apologies, I submitted my answer before seeing your edits. [edit] I learned a lot of `awk` for night :-)

Comment: @mbadawi23: There's nothing to apologize about.  You're entitled, nay encouraged, to provide an answer while there isn't an accepted answer.  Even if an answer has been accepted, if you've got a distinctly different and preferably better answer, then it is still fair game to add a new answer.  And learning from working on an answer is one of the main points of the whole system here on SO.